NPM failing, trying to install x64 dependency on arm64 machine
I have a fresh install of Nuxt 3, that I created on my x64 PC. At this stage, nothing has been changed beyond its initial setup. Git repo
The problem I face is when cloning that to my M1 macbook, running an install fails:
[9:58:44 AM]  ERROR  Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-darwin-x64. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828). Please try npm i again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules directory.

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/jon/CODE/dacuma
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c nuxt prepare

As a further point, I don't know if it's related but I also receive a warning about too low a version of Node, although I can only find an instance of v21 on my machine. I'm looking into this separately.
 WARN  Current version of Node.js (17.4.0) is unsupported and might cause issues.                                                                   9:43:19 AM
       Please upgrade to a compatible version >= 18.0.0.

Any suggestions, gratefully received.
What I've tried:

Updating npm to latest

Clearing npm cache

Removing all references to darwin-x64 from package-lock

Adding it to optionalDependencies in package.json

Installing the module in question by itself, gave an EBADPLATFORM error similar to the one seen in this post

Using sudo npm i


In each of the above, I've always removed package-lock.json and node_modules first.
Update: The existence of Node v17 was the issue. I had followed the guide here to remove everything. However once location it doesn't mention is /(username)/node_modules/node. I found v17 there, it must have been a historic global install. Although I had v18/v20/v21 selected with NVM, the npm i run was making use of this v17.

Install Node v18 with nvm.

I'm on Node v21 at present, is it necessary to downgrade?

To add to that - before I made the post earlier, there was previously some old node installation within /usr/local/include. I removed it, incase that is where the bogus v17 detection was coming from, but it didn't make a change.
Using node -v, or looking in nvm ls, only shows v21 present.

Use an even version because it's the LTS one. If you don't have v18 then you need to install v18 first. And remove any other node instance present on your system.

As for the first part of the question: depends. Do you use any Node v20 features? Have you checked the breaking changes between the v18 and v20? What do your team use? If your project works with v20 you can use that if you want. Its the current LTS.

Aha, it was the existence of v17 within /(username)/node_modules/node that was the issue. Its existence must, in some way, override whatever the nvm selected version is, as switching between v18/v20/v21 wasn't doing anything. With that folder removed, and with a bunch of other node files mentioned in a list on this page https://macpaw.com/how-to/uninstall-node-mac, NOW it uses the nvm selected versions! Thank you for your help and patience everyone. Very much appreciated.

Solution: The existence of Node v17 was the issue. I had followed the guide here to remove everything. However once location it doesn't mention is /(username)/node_modules/node. I found v17 there, it must have been a historic global install. Although I had v18/v20/v21 selected with NVM, the npm i run was making use of this v17.
